# jQuery Re initialize MagnificPopup after ajax loading

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am running into a problem with this function and my Ajax pagination. On the first page of results, this popup works perfectly. But when I use the Ajax pagination, and the next set of results loads, this function no longer works. I guess it needs to be initialized with each ajax refresh? How do I alter the below code accordingly?

`jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type:'iframe',
    alignTop: true,
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    midClick: true 
  });
});`

Thank you!! :)

---

Thank you MarkPlewis! I am using Search & Filter Pro. They provide the following snippet to use to reinitialize your jquery with ajax... How can I implement the first snippet of code I posted, with the following? `//detects the start of an ajax request being made

https://gist.github.com/rmorse/b157004c68870dbd9fb9

`
                $(document).on("sf:ajaxstart", ".searchandfilter", function(){
                  console.log("ajax start");
                });

```
            //detects when the ajax request has finished and the content has been updated
            // - add scripts that apply to your results here
            $(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function(){
                console.log("ajax complete");
                //so load your lightbox or JS scripts here again
            });

            //an event fired when S&F is initialised and S&F scripts have been loaded
            $(document).on("sf:init", ".searchandfilter", function(){
                console.log("S&F JS initialised");
            });
```

`

Comment: Thanks joshdfw, I've updated my answer. Hopefully that will work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. You will need to re-execute that code every time new items are added to the DOM. I don't know which jQuery pagination plugin you're using, but here's a quick demo using "[Infinite Ajax Scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/)". You should be able to adapt this to whatever plugin you're using. The key is to call `activatePopup();` inside the callback function that gets executed after new items have been added to the DOM:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  activatePopup();

  // Initialize the pagination plugin
  var ias = jQuery.ias({
    container:  '#posts',
    item:       '.post',
    pagination: '#pagination',
    next:       '.next'
  });

  // Pagination plugin callback function
  ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
    activatePopup();
  });

  function activatePopup() {
    jQuery('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
      type:'iframe',
      alignTop: true,
      overflowY: 'scroll',
      midClick: true 
    });
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Now that I know which plugin you're using, here's some updated code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  activatePopup();

  // Plugin callback function
  jQuery(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function(){
    activatePopup();
  });

  function activatePopup() {
    jQuery('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
      type:'iframe',
      alignTop: true,
      overflowY: 'scroll',
      midClick: true 
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You rock MarkPlewis! Thank you!

Comment: You guys are awesome! I had recently experienced the same issue with the same plugin and the code above did the trick! So glad I found this post.